# Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-spatial

Here is my error:

> Error Number: 3037
>
> Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT ST_Within(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(12.971201 077.652038)'), 
  ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((13.517837674890684 76.453857421875),(13.838079936422464 77.750244140625),(14.517837674890684 79.453857421875),(13.517837674890684 76.453857421875))')) As geoFenceStatus
```

Comment: What MySQL version you're using?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Don't miss [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39848240/1219280), in my understanding the real answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Invalid GIS data provided to function st\_geometryfromtext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524031/mysql-invalid-gis-data-provided-to-function-st-geometryfromtext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you want to wrap each set of coordinates with their own () like you have done in your query, you need to be using mysql 5.7.9+  the earlier versions do not support it. But that is not all, there is another error. mysql polygons have to be closed

```
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((13.517837674890684 76.453857421875,13.838079936422464 77.750244140625,14.517837674890684 79.453857421875,13.517837674890684 76.453857421875,13.517837674890684 76.453857421875))')
```

And also note that `((` and `))` is the correct syntax