# MySQL 5.7.19 Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext

Tags: mysql, polygon, polygons, mysql-5.7

So I am new at ST_ functions in MySql and I think that I am missing something. I am trying to save a POLYGON in MySql, the problem is that when using the function `ST_GEOMFROMTEXT` and giving the coordinates of the POLYGON taken from Google Maps Javascript API it returns the error: `Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext`.

I've read a lot in Internet but everywhere it mostly says that it's a version problem, the thing here is the I have the most recent one right now (5.7.19)

These are the following queries I've tried

```
# WORKS
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((13.517837674890684 76.453857421875,13.838079936422464 77.750244140625,14.517837674890684 79.453857421875,13.517837674890684 76.453857421875,13.517837674890684 76.453857421875))');

# ALL BELLOW RETURN ERROR
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((19.4254572621497 -99.17182445526123, 19.42574056861496 -99.16570901870728, 19.421551629818985 -99.16558027267456, 19.421288552764135 -99.17210340499878))');
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((-99.17182445526123 19.4254572621497, -99.16570901870728 19.42574056861496, -99.16558027267456 19.421551629818985, -99.17210340499878 19.421288552764135 ))');
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((19.4249108840002 -99.17023658752441, 19.424951356518726 -99.16802644729614, 19.423393157277722 -99.16796207427979, 19.423393157277722 -99.17019367218018))')
```

Does anyone knows why these queries above are failing? Thank you a lot everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try these queries -

```
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((19.4254572621497 -99.17182445526123, 19.42574056861496 -99.16570901870728, 19.421551629818985 -99.16558027267456, 19.421288552764135 -99.17210340499878, 19.4254572621497 -99.17182445526123))');
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((-99.17182445526123 19.4254572621497, -99.16570901870728 19.42574056861496, -99.16558027267456 19.421551629818985, -99.17210340499878 19.421288552764135, -99.17182445526123 19.4254572621497 ))');
SELECT ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((19.4249108840002 -99.17023658752441, 19.424951356518726 -99.16802644729614, 19.423393157277722 -99.16796207427979, 19.423393157277722 -99.17019367218018, 19.4249108840002 -99.17023658752441))')
```

Basically, the polygon needs to be "closed"

Comment: That did it, closing the end point repeating first. Thank you!

Comment: I think it is necessary to clarify that the `POLYGON`s should be closed, i.e. have the same points at the beginning and at the end.